# Override forcedownload behavior in Sitecore

Tags: pdf, sitecore

We had a problem with some of our IE clients failing to download a PDF, even after clicking on the link. We found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23144422/repercussions-of-changing-sitecore-rendering-of-pdfs-from-ashx-to-downloadmedia) resolved our problems: set *forcedownload=true* for PDF mime types in web.config.

However, that created another problem: we are now unable to render a PDF in a browser when we want to. We used to do this with an iframe. However, as you can see, the PDF just downloads, and does not render in the browser.

I learned that the *forcedownload=true* setting is actually a default in a subsequent version of Sitecore (v7.2). So, I'm hesitant to revert that.

So, how do I render a PDF in a browser in this situation?

Comment: I removed the example link, since it no longer exhibits the behavior. See edit comments for details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can leave `forceDownload=false` on the PDF mime type and instead set the following setting to false:

```
<setting name="Media.EnableRangeRetrievalRequest" value="false"/>
```

I faced the same dilema a few months back with the same initial fix. Found out the actual issue last week, I wrote a [blog post](http://jammykam.wordpress.com/2014/07/30/issues-opening-pdf-files-in-ie9-from-sitecore-media-library/) about it. (In fact, I wrote the answer you linked to, I've updated it with the same information now for future visitors)

The issue is basically a combination of Adobe Reader plugin for IE9, chunked transfer encoding and streaming the file directly from the database. I found if you close your browser and try again, or force refresh with Ctrl+F5 it worked fine. Once Sitecore had cached the file to disk it would continue to work for everyone.

The above setting disables chunked transfer encoding, instead sending the file down to the browser as a single piece. This setting was introduced in Sitecore 6.5+

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the flaws in the MediaRequestHandler and in my opinion; the forceDownload option is pretty useless the way it is designed by default. (Why would ever want to configure this option on media extension only?)

You’ll have to basically turn off the forcedownload option again and replace the MediaRequestHandler with your own one. I usually end up with writing my own anyway because if other issues with the default handler, such as dealing properly with CDN’s etc.

In the ProcessRequest pipeline, you can determine if the item should be “downloaded” or not by setting the Content-Disposition header. You basically need to get rid of the default handling of forceDownload and set your headers based on your own logic.

Personally I prefer to set a query string parameter, such as ?dl=1, and base the Content-Disposition header on this. You could also extend the MediaItem template to contain a default behavior on each item or sub tree (leverage from Sitecore inheritance and standard values), and potentially you could thereby also define (override) a specific filename on each item for the attachment part in the Content-Disposition header.

When rendering the link, you can leverage from the properties collection (write a suitable extension method or similar), so that you can clearly mark your code that the link is meant for download, but still leverage from the built in field render methods. Thereby you eliminate the risk of messing up the page editor etc.

/ Mikael

Comment: Great ideas here, but I'm going with the advice of @jammykam, since it's just a setting, and the caveats are acceptable.

Answer (score -1):

You have to disable range retrieval request in web.config by setting its value to false.

```
<setting name="Media.EnableRangeRetrievalRequest" value="false" />
```

MediaRequestHandler enables Sitecore to download PDF content partially in range using HTTP 206 Status code. You can also overwrite MediaRequestHandler and write your own custom implementation to handle media request.